# Obtain address from PostGIS OSM data like Nominatim does?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

We currently use the Nominatim service to do address lookups. We want to store the OSM data in our own servers as our usage gets higher.

How do I calculate the address of a given coordinate, like how Nominatim does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest just using Nominatim installed locally. See [installation instructions](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation)

That will give you minimum integration risk, and an equivalent result.

Comment: Does not work on Windows. You can get the app to start but it just crashes. The authors say that it will not run on Windows.

Comment: @AndrewScottEvans perhaps a Docker install could be an option. I haven't tried it, but there are some mature-looking activities on github. In 2019 there are probably other options - Pelias is my current preferred, although the question specifically wanted something like Nominatim.